# Spring cannot find key store file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, restlet-2.0

I have this file structure;

[image]

Then on my beans xml config I have;

[image]

But when I start the server up I get a `FileNotFoundException` /store/thestore.jks

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The leading `/` in `/store/thestore.jks`? Try with `store/thestore.jks`. I can't think of anything else; it looks fine IMO.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ still getting; `java.io.FileNotFoundException: store\thestore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: Can you copy `thestore.jks` into `resources` (outside `/store`) and modify the entry to `<prop key="keyStorePath">classpath:thestore.jks</prop>`? Also try with `file:thestore.jks`. Additionally, like @11thdimension said, update the question with your stack trace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to source code here [com.noelios.restlet.util.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.restlet/1.1.10_3/com/noelios/restlet/util/DefaultSslContextFactory.java#DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext%28%29)

```
190            FileInputStream keyStoreInputStream = null;
191            try {
192                keyStoreInputStream = ((this.keyStorePath != null) && (!"NONE"
193                        .equals(this.keyStorePath))) ? new FileInputStream(
194                        this.keyStorePath) : null;
195                keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, this.keyStorePassword);
```

It's using `FileInputStream`, which means it will try to read file from the file system and not from the JAR itself.

You have to put `jks` file outside JAR and provide absolute path to it.

For example

```
<prop key="keyStorePath">C:/store/thestore.jks</prop>
```

Comment: Providing the absolute path of the file outside of the project solved my problem